# dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, dpkg-buildpackage

I'm seeing this error when trying to package. The so file exists and it matches the library in the so. Also the same library is the installed package, so there is no mismatch there.

**Error Message**

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0 (used by debian/libonnxruntime1-cuda/usr/lib/libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so)
```

***Linked libraries***

```
root@desktop:/debout/libonnxruntime-cuda_1.11.0.orig# ldd debian/libonnxruntime1-cuda/usr/lib/libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffa6845000)
        libcublas.so.11 => /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcublas.so.11 (0x0000ffff97fba000)
        libcudnn.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.8 (0x0000ffff97f6d000)
        libcufft.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcufft.so.10 (0x0000ffff82228000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000ffff821f7000)
        **libcudart.so.11.0 => /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0 (0x0000ffff82147000)**
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffff81f62000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffff81eb7000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffff81e93000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff81d20000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffffa6815000)
        libcublasLt.so.11 => /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so.11 (0x0000ffff6fa00000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x0000ffff6f9e8000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000ffff6f9d4000)
```

***Library exists***

```
root@desktop:/debout/libonnxruntime-cuda_1.11.0.orig# ls -la /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Oct  5  2021 /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0 -> libcudart.so.11.4.148
```

***Debian Package has same path for library***

```
root@desktop:/debout/libonnxruntime-cuda_1.11.0.orig# dpkg -S /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0
cuda-cudart-11-4: /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0
```

***Package is installed***

```
root@desktop:/debout/libonnxruntime-cuda_1.11.0.orig# apt list --installed | grep cudart
cuda-cudart-11-4/unknown,unknown,now 11.4.148-1 arm64 [installed]
cuda-cudart-dev-11-4/unknown,unknown,now 11.4.148-1 arm64 [installed]
```

***I also tried to use the shlibs.local file.***

```
root@desktop:/debout/libonnxruntime-cuda_1.11.0.orig# more shlibs.local
libcudart 11 libcudart
```

Anyone encounter this error/issue before?

Comment: I solved my issues, it wanted 11.0 in the shlibs.local file instead of 11 libcudart 11.0 libcudart
 
 
The objdump let me know what version to use. I was previously using 11.
 
root@desktop:/debout/libonnxruntime-cuda_1.11.0.orig# objdump -p /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/sbsa-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0 | sed -n -e's/^[[:space:]]*SONAME[[:space:]]*//p' | LC_ALL=C sed -r -e's/([0-9])\.so\./\1-/; s/\.so(\.|$)//; y/_/-/; s/(.*)/\L&/'
libcudart11.0